# How to automatically convert Rating from int to Panel with Images in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Need help with one thing. I have `DataGrid`, binding it to this class:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public Statistics Stats { get; set; }
}
```

This is XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="56,49,12,12" Name="booksDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" ColumnWidth="*" MinWidth="400" MinHeight="250">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="titleColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" Header="Title" Width="2*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="authorColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Author}" Header="Author" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="tagsColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Tags}" Header="Tags" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="yearColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Year}" Header="Year" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ratingColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Rating}" Header="Rating" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But I want to show Rating not like a number, but like a five images of stars. How can I convert int value to something like a panel with images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public Statistics Stats { get; set; }

  public string displayRating 
    {
        get
        {
            if (Rating > 0)
            {
                var temp = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < Rating; i++)
                {
                    temp += "*";
                }
                return temp;
            }
            return "No rating found";
        } 
    }
}
```

if your `Rating` property = 5, the `displayRating` property will be `"*****"`. 
You could bind that `displayRating` property to your gridview like this:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ratingColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=displayRating}" Header="Rating" Width="*" />
```

**EDIT:**

If the maximum amount of stars you are going to need isn't a super big number (like 30+) you could just make a .jpg for each rating.
So you make a .jpg file with 1*, you make a .jpg with 2*..
Then in your displayRating string do the following:

```
  public string displayRating 
    {
        get{ return "pathToYourJpg" + Rating + ".jpg";}
    }
```

lets say that you have the following Jpg's:

```
c:/users/desktop/rating1.jpg
c:/users/desktop/rating2.jpg
c:/users/desktop/rating3.jpg
c:/users/desktop/rating4.jpg
```

if your rating is 4, the displayProperty rating will return  `"c:/users/desktop/rating4.jpg"` Use this path to bind it to your datagrid.

Something like this (not sure tho, havent actually done this myself, but it should be something like this):

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=displayRating}" Stretch="Fill" Height="100" Width="100" />
```

this is just off the top of my head.. it's one way how you could do it, not saying this is the best one :)

Comment: Thousand, thanks for advice, but it really doesn't look pretty, i want to do something, like in the uTorrent. I need to use images.